# OnHover HTML5 audio on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari

I created a simple nav bar with on-hover mp3/ogg audio playback.
It works on all browsers except Safari on Windows, but judging by the autor it should work on it too.
Can somebody take a look on Mac and let me know is it working http://goo.gl/h2K6PN

```
<audio id="aruba" controls preload="auto">
  <source src="audio/Aruba.mp3"></source>
  <source src="audio/Aruba.ogg"></source>
</audio>

<ul class="top-level">
<li><a href="#" class="palm-tree" id="arubaplay">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
window.onload=function(){

// collecting audio files
var aruba = document.getElementById('aruba');
var arubaplay=document.getElementById('arubaplay');

arubaplay.onmouseover=function(){
 aruba.play();
 return false;
};
```

Comment: Safari for Windows is deprecated, maybe it doesn't support the new HTML5 standard anymore? besides, almost nobody is using it anymore

Comment: Yep, Safari on Windows is rare, but im curious does it work on a Mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Safari does not support HTML Audio tags without Quicktime properly installed. Your link works on OS X Safari.